# Web browser component (AxSHDocVw) forcing to run 32-bit IE version on 64-bit OS

Tags: internet-explorer, automation, 64-bit

I plan on deploying a component that makes heavy use of the AxSHDocVw to automate IE on a server (making screen captures of various sites). The server in question is 64-bit win2k8 box. Because Adobe can't get their friggin act together and release a 64-bit flash player, I need the AxSHDocVw to run the 32-bit version of IE so that it renders flash.

My question is, is it possible to force the AxSHDocVw component to use the 32-bit version of the browser? If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run "it" in a 32-bit process.